# Levi-Cevita symbol in two dimensions

Tags: tensor-calculus, definition, notation

They won't let me delete this question so now no one will know.

Answer (score 1):

The components are
$\epsilon_{12} = 1$,
$\epsilon_{21} = -1$,
$\epsilon_{11} = \epsilon_{22} = 0$,
you get $\epsilon_{ij} a_i b_j = a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1$.

If $a_i$, $b_j$ indicates the component of two vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ w.r.t. to a unit orthogonal basis, this is the component of the vector product $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$ in the direction orthogonal to the plane defined by this two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia article on [the Levi Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Two_dimensions):

$$\epsilon_{12}=1$$
$$\epsilon_{21}=-1$$
$$\epsilon_{11}=\epsilon_{22}=0$$